# How can I make font awesome icons clickable with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-awesome

Im trying to give this set of font awesome icons to be clickable ( so when I click on them, I get directed to the page I want)

```
<i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i>

<i class="fas fa-utensils"></i>

<i class="fas fa-newspaper"></i>

<i class="fas fa-user"></i>

<i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>
```

How can I accomplish this with Javascript or if there is another way to work around it? I know that you can do this by wrapping the icons with `<a href=""` , but I'm just looking for another way to do it

Comment: Why would you not want to use an anchor tag, if it is to direct to another page? Don't forget that an onClick window.location won't be indexed by web crawlers or as accessible as a standard <a href=...>

Answer (score 1):

onclick Event

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers

Example

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Syntax
In HTML:

```
<element onclick="myScript">
```

In JavaScript:

```
object.onclick = function(){myScript};
```

In JavaScript, using the addEventListener() method:

```
object.addEventListener("click", myScript);
```

Comment: w3 schools is not a good place to go for references. Typically content there is over-simplified, as it's aimed as beginners, and a lot of the code samples don't follow good coding practices. Consider updating with MDN or Mozilla documentation link instead.